# Why does the animation reset on slideToggle()? (jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I've positioned a div (fixed) at the bottom of the viewport to act as a contact tab, when then tab is clicked it triggers a panel to slide out, this is working correctly.

I'm also trying to get the tab to slide out when it is clicked and slide back in when then close button is clicked on the panel.

The tab has the ID `#menufixed`

The panel close button has the class `.nest-custom-button-wrapper`

This is the JS I'm currently using which is causing a weird animation reset everytime the slideToggle is triggered:

```
<script> 
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#menufixed").click(function(){
        jQuery("#menufixed").slideToggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

**View the issue:**

https://content.screencast.com/users/Vanstone/folders/Default/media/aa25e806-e0c0-4f8c-b112-e1162ede41da/11new.mp4

How can I get the tab to stay hidden and only trigger the slide up when the .nest-custom-button-wrapper is clicked?

**EDIT:**

CSS:

```
#menufixed {
    z-index: 99999999!important;
    display: block!important;
    position: fixed!important;
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you have this in your CSS for `#menufix`

```
display: block!important
```

jQuery is trying to hide the element but this style is overriding it. If you remove just the `!important` part of that style it should work fine.

**Updated CSS**

```
#menufixed {
    z-index: 99999999!important;
    display: block; /* removed the !important style */
    position: fixed!important;
    margin: 0 auto!important;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 45%;
    width: 10%;
    height: 40px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
```

In order to get the button tab to slide up from `.nest-custom-button-wrapper` you can just add another click event to slideToggle the `#menufixed`

**JS Code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#menufixed").click(function(){
        jQuery("#menufixed").slideToggle();
    });
    jQuery('.nest-custom-button-wrapper').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // not sure if this is an 'a' tag or not

        jQuery("#menufixed").slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Joe this worked perfectly thank you for your help! :)